# Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported?

Tags: iphone

i have one normal UIViewCOntroller(home) in which i have IBAction Method like

```
- (IBAction)goto1:(id)sender
{

self. goto1Controller.modalTransitionStyle =   UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:self. goto1Controller animated:YES];
}
```

it works fine. goto1Controller is a normal UIViewcontroller in which i have used one action
through userdefined Navigation controller through which i go to another controller like
  in self.goto1Controller

```
- (IBAction)goto2:(id)sender
 {      
    [userdefNavController pushViewController:goto2Controller animated:YES];
[self presentModalViewController: userdefNavController animated:NO];
}
```

i come back from goto2Controller to  goto1Controller through

```
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

it works fine...but when i use this same method([self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];) to go to home i have to press twice...
and also when i press  - (IBAction)goto2:(id)sender again after coming from goto2Controller
crash is happened..error also "Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported"
any solution?
i have in my viewdidload as

```
 userdefNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not necessarily be mixing presentModalViewController and pushViewController on the navigation controller. There are different reasons to use each of them. Here is what the [view controller programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1) says:

> Most commonly, applications use modal
>   view controllers as a temporary
>   interruption in order to obtain key
>   information from the user. However,
>   you can also use modally presented
>   view controllers to implement
>   alternate interfaces for your
>   application at specific times.

I you have hierarchical data, create a drill down by displaying successive view controllers using -pushNavigationController:aniamted:. When the error message says you cannot push the same instance, it doesn't mean you can't create a new instance of the same class. Just create a new instance of the view controller you want to push.

If you have a special case in which you need to present something out of the ordinary to the user, the use -presetnModalViewController: